# Is it possible de read and modify conflicted files in a svn hook

Tags: svn, hook

I'm wondering if it is possible to read the two merging files and modify the result in a svn hook in order to prevent a conflict I know how to fix automatically?

Before a delivery, modified files are audited, if the audit is OK, the header of the file is updated.
85% of the conflicts are due to those updates.

Is it possible de develop a script reading the files in the pre-commit, sort in the right way the headers and commit a correct header without conflict?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Pre-commit hook is not best place (you must commit *something* in order to fire hook, your hook have to block this commit and perform prepared "nested")
2. I suppose, somehow better choice may be special merge-tool (in which you'll have script, performing merge under hood)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will wheck for good merge-tool.